# Local MySQL connection fails from tcp

Tags: mysql, mariadb, ubuntu-16.04

After upgrading my vps with Ubuntu 16.04 (and after a month or so) I need to use the MySQL server that was running there. Actually it was a MariaDB instance but it seems it's not making any difference. Since I couldn't connect with a ssh tunnel as I always did, I tried accessing from the remote shell directly and using the `mysql` cli interface it works. The matter is I **need** to use the MySQL server from the local IP (for remote tunneling or for mysqli on php). 
Trying to force the tcp connection with `mysql --protocol tcp` I get `ERROR 1698 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'`, while php gives this warning: `mysqli::__construct(): (HY000/1698): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'`.

I tried purging MariaDB, reinstalling it, trying with MySQL package itself, removing every mysql configuration and file, but with no results.

The configuration always includes `bind-address = 127.0.0.1` and related port and it's not commented but it seems useless.

Any ideas?

Comment: Take a look at [this Q&A](http://serverfault.com/a/614109/37681)

Answer (score 0):

I found it out. 
There was an `unix_socket` plugin associated with the root account. 
I just ran `update user set plugin='';` and restarted the `mysql` process and it worked.