# Why is MySQL connecting through socket even though I'm specifying host and port?

Tags: mysql

When trying to connect to a MySQL database running on port 3306 on localhost (using the command line tool `mysql`), I'm getting the error:

> ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)

Here's the command I'm using:

```
> mysql -h localhost -P 3306
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)
```

Specifying user and password also doesn't work:

```
> mysql -h localhost -P 3306 -u dbuser -p
Password:
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)
```

Why is it trying to use a UNIX socket file (as it seems to be doing here) when I'm specifying host and port?

Comment: See this older answer of mine: http://serverfault.com/a/614109/37681

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use `127.0.0.1` instead of `localhost`:

```
> mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -P 3306
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 8347701
Server version: 5.6.35-80.0-log Percona Server (GPL), Release 80.0, 
Revision f113994f31
...
```

You're in!

Comment: Still this does not answer: `Why`

Answer (score 3):

MySQL client infers the protocol from the provided host.

> For a given connection, if the transport protocol is not specified explicitly, it is determined implicitly. For example, connections to localhost result in a socket file connection on Unix and Unix-like systems, and a TCP/IP connection to 127.0.0.1 otherwise.

Source: [MySQL Docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/transport-protocols.html)

To avoid that you can specify the [protocol](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/transport-protocols.html) yourself:

```
> mysql -h localhost -P 3306 --protocol TCP
```

You should be able to log in :D.

Comment: Thank you I have been stuck on this for hours. Subtle differences between mariadb and mysql.