# PuTTY Reverse Tunnel to MySQL

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, mysql, ssh-tunnel, putty

I have:

- A local `Windows 10` PC running MySQL Server 8.0.33 on port `33060`.
- A remote `Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS` VPS running MySQL Server 8.0.33 on port `3306`.

I want to create a reverse tunnel using PuTTY on my Windows PC so that my Ubuntu VPS is able to connect to my local MySQL instance running on port 33060.

For example, I'd like to connect via this command:

```bash
username@localhost:~$ mysql -h localhost -P 33060 -u test -ptest
```

*Note: I've already created a MySQL test user on my Windows PC with the following settings:*

| Name | Value |
| --- | --- |
| Login Name | test |
| Authentication Type | caching_sha2_password |
| Limit to Hosts Matching | % |
| Password | test |
| Account Limits | Unlimited - 0/0/0/0 |
| Administrative Roles | Full Privileges - Everything is Checked |

However this happens when trying to connect:

```bash
username@localhost:~$ mysql -h localhost -P 33060 -u test -ptest
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'test'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

```bash
username@localhost:~$ mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -P 33060 -u test -ptest
ERROR 2007 (HY000): Protocol mismatch; server version = 11, client version = 10
```

Note: If it makes any difference, `AllowTcpForwarding` is enabled in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` on my Ubuntu VPS and the OpenSSH service was restarted via `service ssh restart`.

Here's my PuTTY configuration:

[image: PuTTY configuration]

I've tried all kinds of combinations of settings but my Ubuntu VPS can't connect to my Windows MySQL server.

For what it's worth, I was able to have my Ubuntu VPS successfully connect to PHP's built-in webserver running on my Windows PC with basically the same PuTTY settings (just different ports):

```bash
PS C:\test> php -S localhost:9876
[Tue May 23 23:10:50 2023] PHP 8.0.8 Development Server (http://localhost:9876) started
[Tue May 23 23:11:01 2023] [::1]:64617 Accepted
[Tue May 23 23:11:01 2023] [::1]:64617 [200]: GET /
[Tue May 23 23:11:01 2023] [::1]:64617 Closing
```

```bash
username@localhost:~$ curl localhost:9876
Hello World
```

But getting back to MySQL, is this a configuration issue with PuTTY, MySQL Server on Windows, or something else entirely?

Answer (score 0):

What ended up solving the problem was changing the PuTTY settings to:

[image: PuTTY settings]

Apparently, port `33060` uses the [X protocol](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-port-reference/en/mysql-ports-reference-tables.html#:%7E:text=MySQL%20clients%20to%20the%20MySQL%20server%20(X%20Protocol)), not the classic MySQL protocol.

From my testing, it seems changing the port makes a difference with the Ubuntu MySQL client (even though the Windows MySQL server port is exactly the same and `SELECT @@global.protocol_version;` shows `10`).

After changing the PuTTY settings, I was then able to connect on my Ubuntu VPS with this command:

```bash
mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -P 3307 -u test -ptest
```

However, running the same command with `localhost` instead of `127.0.0.1` gives an `Access Denied` error. After some digging, I found [this post](https://serverfault.com/a/614109/618191) which explains:

*"In MySQL, the localhost keyword is reserved for connection using the MySQL socket and you should use the ip-address 127.0.0.1 for TCP connections to the MySQL network port on 127.0.0.1."*

---

The `ssh` equivalent command (built into Windows and enabled in April 2018 update) is:

```bash
ssh -R 3307:localhost:33060 username@your_ip -i "C:\path\to\your\id_rsa" -o "StrictHostKeyChecking=no"
```

---

To create a persistent reverse tunnel as a Windows service, see [this autossh guide](https://docs.keeper.io/keeper-connection-manager/supported-protocols/persistent-reverse-ssh-tunnel/connecting-via-reverse-ssh-tunnel).

There are a few oversights and errors in the guide though.

When installing `cygwin`, you'll need to install these packages:

- `cygrunsrv`
- `openssh`
- `autossh`

Then allow your Windows account to Log On as a Service:

WinKey + R -> gpedit.msc

Computer Configuration -> Windows Settings -> Security Settings -> Local Policies -> User Rights Assignment -> Log on as a service -> Add your username.

To test your `autossh` connection in a `cygwin` instance:

```bash
autossh -M 20000 -R 3307:localhost:33060 username@your_ip -i "C:\path\to\your\id_rsa" -o "StrictHostKeyChecking=no"
```

If that works, open PowerShell as an admin (important) and run:

```bash
C:\cygwin64\bin\cygrunsrv.exe -I AutoSSH -p /usr/bin/autossh -a '-M 20000 -R 3307:localhost:33060 username@your_ip -i "C:\\path\\to\\your\\id_rsa" -o "StrictHostKeyChecking=no"' -e AUTOSSH_NTSERVICE=yes
```

Note the double backslashes.

Later, if the service doesn't start and you need to try again, run this command in the admin PowerShell to delete the service:

```bash
sc.exe delete AutoSSH
```

In `cygwin` you can find the AutoSSH log in `/var/log/AutoSSH.log` to diagnose errors.